# Obtain type of member having pointer to member

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a template class that will accept any type, as a parameter, which has some public member which can be used as an index (of type int, short, unsigned, etc). I would like my template class to accept the type of object to be used as well as information which field of this type my template class should use as the 'key' field.

I wrote something like below (just an example to give you an idea of how I want to use it), but it doesn't work. The problem is that I am trying to use a pointer to member as the information of which field of the type specified as Value should my template class use to get the Key. I wanted to use decltype to obtain the type of the pointed field, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to get the type of the field which is pointed by poiter to member? I tried decay function but with no success. Instead of having "int A::*" I want to get just "int".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class V, class M, M member>
struct MyClass
{
    using key_type = decltype(member);
    vector<key_type> v;

    MyClass()
    {
        v.push_back(1);
        // ERROR - error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int A::*, std::allocator<int A::*> >::push_back(int)'
    }
};

struct A 
{ 
    int x; 
    int key;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<A, decltype(&A::key), &A::key> mc;
}
```

Comment: Note that the following succeeds: `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(member), M>);` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: A few minor corrections to the template parameters:

```
template <class C, typename Mem, Mem C::*member>
struct MyClass {
    using key_type = Mem;
    vector<key_type> v;

    MyClass()
    {
        v.push_back(1);
    }
};
```

And the instantiation:

```
MyClass<A, decltype(A::key), &A::key> mc;
```

Will do the trick.

Explanation:

1. You want the third parameter to be a pointer to the member of the class you pass as the first parameter. That requires the pointer to member syntax `C::*`. The type `Mem` is the type of the "pointee".
2. To obtain the type of the member, and not the type of the "pointer to member" you need to supply `decltype` with either a member access expression, or a qualified id. Hence the change there.

---

You can reduce the amount of template parameters to 2, by passing only the pointer to member type (as you did originally), and using a meta-function to extract the relevant information from it.

```
template<typename T>
struct point_to_mem;

// Meta-function to extract type information from a pointer to a member.
template<class C, typename T>
struct point_to_mem<T C::*> {
    using member_type = T;
    using class_type  = C;
};

template <typename PointToMem, PointToMem member>
struct MyClass {
    using key_type = typename point_to_mem<PointToMem>::member_type;
    vector<key_type> v;

    MyClass()
    {
        v.push_back(1);
    }
};

// ...

MyClass<decltype(&A::key), &A::key> mc;
```

---

Finally, with C++17, you can make this really economical and reduce the template parameters to 1:

```
template <auto member>
struct MyClass {
    using key_type = typename point_to_mem<decltype(member)>::member_type;
    // As before
};

// ...

int main()
{
    MyClass<&A::key> mc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That sovled my problem. Just one more question: any difference between 'class' and 'typename' keywords?

Comment: @YotKay - They mean the same for template type parameters. I just prefer to use one to document I'm expecting an actual class type, and another when expecting any type.

Comment: Wow, the short version is much better. But why C++17 is needed? What lacks in C++11 to do the same?

Comment: @YotKay - The ability to pass a non-type template parameter (such as a pointer to member) with a placeholder type (such as `auto`) to be deduced.

Comment: Last question: I've never seen this: "struct point_to_mem<T C::*>". What is this called?

Comment: Ahh, stupid me, didn't see above, this is specialization of template point_to_mem.